# A text box whitch submits on every letter pressed

Tags: php, javascript, events, instant

I have a php search engine and i want a java scripted text box that submits on every letter pressed. The effect that i want is the Google instant. My site is simple so it will go fast.

```
<form method='post' action='?&id=search' name='form' >
   Search:<br>
   <input name='search' value='<?php echo "$sq"; ?>' type='text' class='form2' style='font-weight:bold;' size='25' onUnfocus='send()'> 
   <input type='submit' class='button' value='Search'>
```

thank you, very very much

Comment: Load results via AJAX, you can make it easier by using jQuery.

Comment: On 'every key press' is seldom a good idea. Better to use a timer to make a request every time the user has stopped typing for x milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery

```
$("input[name=search]").keyup(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax.search.php",
        data: "q=" + $(this).val(),
        success: function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This implements exactly what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your submitted code, I'm gonna assume it works, but not for every key pressed, because you need to use either [onkeyup](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) or [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Using a standard form submission method would reload the page. What you'll need is to submit the form data using AJAX and dynamically update the results.

`unFocus` is also not a valid event (you are thinking of `onblur`) but what you want is `onkeyup`.

The javascript event handler should send the form data and the success handler should update the results.